# Different ParcelJs bundles for web and mobil users

Tags: requirejs, durandal-2.0, parceljs

I have an old Durandal site that are using requireJS for module loading.
We are building 3 different main.js bundles. Web, Mobile and one for the site embedded in a WPF desktop app.

The same goes for the css/scss.

My motivation for moving the build process to something like ParcelJs is because today we are using a mix of gulp, durandal weyland (cli) and the build in asp.net mvc bundler, not pretty (:

Are parcel up to the job? working with requireJS and building different bundles?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am trying to move Durandal app to Webpack but having a couple of problems in changing the requierjs dependeny loading.

Comment: No I kept the old package manager